# DataGridViewComboBoxCell : How to set selected value when adding a row?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have this form that lets user choose a (Code - Product) item from a comboxbox. input quantity and price and Add it to a list.

[image]

Loading the inventories to the form

```
private List<Inventory> inventories = new Inventory().read_inventory();
```

Setting the ComboBox with values

```
private void set_drop_down_inventory()
{
        cb_inventory.DisplayMember = "name";
        cb_inventory.DataSource = inventories;
        cb_inventory.ResetText();
        cb_inventory.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

When a user selects a product, it will create a new instance.

```
private void cb_inventory_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var selected_inventory = (cb_inventory.SelectedItem as Inventory);

        sales_order_detail = new Sales_Order_Detail(selected_inventory, 0);

        tx_description.Text = selected_inventory.description;
        tx_price.Text = selected_inventory.get_price_str();

 }
```

Once the user adds the item it triggers this code.

```
private void btn_add_item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        // Set the inputted data into the instance before adding to the list
        sales_order_detail.description = tx_description.Text.ToString();
        sales_order_detail.quantity = tx_quantity.Value;
        sales_order_detail.price = Convert.ToDecimal(tx_price.Text);

        // Adding the instances to a List
        sales_order.sales_order_details.Add(sales_order_detail);

        // Sets the Datagrid to provide the data+
        initialize_datagrid(sales_order_detail);

}
```

This is how i initialize the datagrid because i need to manually display the columns -- this is where i am not sure what to do - i believe i do not need to manually add a new row every time a user adds an item because this datagrid is bounded to the List<>, so whatever instance is added to the List<> it will be added to the grid when i trigger the dgv.Refresh()

```
private void initialize_datagrid(Sales_Order_Detail sales_order_detail)
{

        dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Clear();
        dgv_sales_order_details.DataSource = null;
        dgv_sales_order_details.Refresh();
        dgv_sales_order_details.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        // Set the datasource to the list where the item is added
        dgv_sales_order_details.DataSource = sales_order.sales_order_details;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn product_code_col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        DataGridViewColumn description_col = new DataGridViewColumn();
        DataGridViewColumn quantity_col = new DataGridViewColumn();
        DataGridViewColumn price_col = new DataGridViewColumn();
        DataGridViewColumn account_col = new DataGridViewColumn();

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell product_cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell description_cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell amount_cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

        product_cell.DisplayMember = "name";
        // They have the same Datasource as the combobox above.
        product_cell.DataSource = inventories;

        product_code_col.CellTemplate = product_cell;
        product_code_col.DataPropertyName = nameof(sales_order_detail.inventory.name); //This binds the value to your column
        product_code_col.HeaderText = "Code";
        product_code_col.Name = "name";

        description_col.CellTemplate = description_cell;
        description_col.DataPropertyName = nameof(sales_order_detail.description);
        description_col.HeaderText = "Description";
        description_col.Name = "description";

        quantity_col.CellTemplate = amount_cell;
        quantity_col.DataPropertyName = nameof(sales_order_detail.quantity);
        quantity_col.HeaderText = "Quantity";
        quantity_col.Name = "quantity";
        quantity_col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00";
        quantity_col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

        price_col.CellTemplate = amount_cell;
        price_col.DataPropertyName = nameof(sales_order_detail.price);
        price_col.HeaderText = "Price";
        price_col.Name = "price";
        price_col.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00";
        price_col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

        dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(product_code_col);
        dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(description_col);
        dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(quantity_col);
        dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(price_col);


        dgv_sales_order_details.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
}
```

This is the result when the item is added but as you can see the combobox column has not displayed value, it only shows the value when i click the combobox column. and when i change the value in the combobox above the list, the value in the combobox column also changes. it seems that they are binded.

[image]

My Goal is to be able add a row to the datagrid where the comboboxcolumn displays what i selected and to fix to combobox duplicated selection.

Please comment if it needs more clarification so i could correct it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it, this is my solution. This is best solution i've come up so far. Please comment if you have any correction. so we could improve it. I hope this will help others too.

1. Created a DataGridView Handler so i could reuse it in the other forms and add more conditions for it be flexible.

   ```
   namespace Project.Classes
   {
        public static class DGV_Handler
        {

            public static DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateInventoryComboBox()
            {
                 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

                 // This lets the combo box display the data selected

                 // I set the datasource with new instance because if i use the Datasource used in the combobox in the item selection. the combobox in the grid and that combox will be binded. if i change one combobox the other one follows.
                 combo.DataSource = new Inventory().read_inventory();
                 combo.DataPropertyName = "inventory_id";
                 combo.DisplayMember = "name";
                 combo.ValueMember = "inventory_id";
                 combo.Name = "inventory_id";
                 combo.HeaderText = "Code";
                 combo.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                 return combo;
           }

           public static DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateGLAccountComboBox()
           {
                 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                 combo.DataSource = new Account().read();
                 combo.DataPropertyName = "gl_account_sales";
                 combo.DisplayMember = "account_name";
                 combo.ValueMember = "account_id";
                 combo.Name = "account_id";
                 combo.HeaderText = "Account";
                 combo.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                 return combo;
          }

          public static DataGridViewTextBoxColumn CreateTextBox(string dataproperty, string headertext, string name, bool is_numbers)
          {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textbox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                textbox.DataPropertyName = dataproperty;
                textbox.HeaderText = headertext;
                textbox.Name = name;

               if (is_numbers)
               {
                  textbox.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00";
                  textbox.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
               }            
               return textbox;
          }

      }
   }
   ```
2. When the form is loaded i initialize the datagrid like this.

   ```
   private void initialize_datagrid()
   {
       dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Clear();
       dgv_sales_order_details.Refresh();
       dgv_sales_order_details.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

       dgv_sales_order_details.DataSource = bindingSource1;

       dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(DGV_Handler.CreateInventoryComboBox());
       dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(DGV_Handler.CreateTextBox("description","Description", "description", false));
       dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(DGV_Handler.CreateTextBox("quantity","Quantity","quantity", true));
       dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(DGV_Handler.CreateTextBox("price", "Price", "price", true));
       dgv_sales_order_details.Columns.Add(DGV_Handler.CreateGLAccountComboBox());

       dgv_sales_order_details.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
       dgv_sales_order_details.RowHeadersVisible = false;

       dgv_sales_order_details.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

   }
   ```
3. Code when adding a new row

   ```
   private void btn_add_item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(validate_selection())
       {
           // Set the properties to be included in the DGV Column
           var selected_row = (cb_inventory.SelectedValue as Inventory);
           var selected_gl_account = (cb_gl_account.SelectedValue as Account);

           string description = tx_description.Text;
           decimal quantity = tx_quantity.Value;
           decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(tx_price.Text);
           int gl_account_id = selected_gl_account.account_id;

           // When something new is added to the bindingsource, the DGV will be refresh
           bindingSource1.Add(new Sales_Order_Detail(selected_row, description, quantity, price, 0, gl_account_id));

           clear_item_selection();
       }
   }
   ```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn c = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
c.Name = "ComboColumn";
c.DataSource = dataTable;
c.ValueMember = "ID";
c.DisplayMember = "Item";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(c);
```

To select a particular value you set the Value property of a given cell.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexYouWant].Cells["ComboColumn"].Value = 1;
```

Note that the type here is important!  **IF** you say you get a `System.FormatException`. This can be caused by setting the wrong type to the value.

When you set the value to 1 you are assigning an int - if for some reason you have strings in the ID column you will get the `System.FormatException` exception you are seeing.

If the types differ you need to either update the DataTable definition or set the value to a string:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexYouWant].Cells["ComboColumn"].Value = "1";
```

for adding rows you might need

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
int z=0;
 for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView1.comlumncount; a++)
         {

            dataGridView1.Rows[z].Cells[a].Value = "yourvalue";
            z++;
         }
```

for your reference check this [Link](https://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/combobox-with-datagridview-in-c/) you might get your problem solved

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. I'll try to work with these

Comment: This works when i add a row, but when i add another row the existing rows will not display the selected value anymore.

Comment: have updated link in answer let me know if it didnt worked for you

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. i also solved it just now. i'm going to check this if i can learn something new. i'm going to post my solution now. maybe you guys could refine it.